How can we color each pair of contours with specific color?
I have this plot from ContourPlot and want to color each pair with specific color starting from inner contours.
ContourPlot[ 
 En/2 Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[2 - En^2/(4 B), 3, B] - 
   Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[2 - En^2/(4 B), 2, B] == 0, {B, 0, 
  30}, {En, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, ContourStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[1], Black}, 
 ImageSize -> 300]        



You'll need a definition of "inner" for "starting from inner contours"....
plot = ContourPlot[
   En/2 Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[2 - En^2/(4 B), 3, B] - 
     Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[2 - En^2/(4 B), 2, B] == 0, {B, 0, 
    30}, {En, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> All, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, ContourStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[1], Black}, 
   ImageSize -> 300];

nlines = Cases[Normal@plot, _Line, Infinity];
gclines = Cases[plot, _Line, Infinity];

innerpt = {0, 0}; (* distance above/below defines inner *)

abovebelow = GroupBy[nlines, Sign[#[[1, 1, 2]] - innerpt[[2]]] &];

abovebelow = 
  SortBy[#, RegionDistance[#, Point@innerpt] &] & /@ abovebelow;

(* put graphic complex lines back in *)
abovebelow = abovebelow /. Thread[nlines -> gclines];

colors = {Green, Red, Blue, Yellow, Cyan, Black};
abovebelow = 
  Partition[Riffle[Take[colors, Length@#], #], 2] & /@ abovebelow;

plot /. (Last[#] -> # & /@ Join @@ Values@abovebelow)


Alternatively, you can skip replacing nlines by gclines in the last modification to abovebelow and just plot nlines:
Graphics[{
  AbsoluteThickness[1], (* b/c original styling is lost *)
  Riffle[Take[colors, Length@abovebelow[-1]], abovebelow[-1]],
  Riffle[Take[colors, Length@abovebelow[1]], abovebelow[1]]
  },
 Options@plot]


@Michal E2, That is awesome! One more thing please, if I want to split each pair in a single plot, say only green and remove others, then red and remove others, and so on

plot = ContourPlot[
   En/2 Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[2 - En^2/(4 B), 3, B] - 
     Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[2 - En^2/(4 B), 2, B] == 0, {B, 0, 
    30}, {En, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, ContourStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[1], Black}, 
   ImageSize -> 300];


We can at first label the lines and select suitable colors later.

Block[{e = 1}, (plot // Normal) /. 
  Line[pts_] :> {Text[Style[e++, Blue, 15], First@pts], Line[pts]}]


colors = {Cyan, Yellow, Green, Red, Blue, Cyan, Blue, Red, Black, 
   Yellow, Green};
Block[{e = 1}, plot /. Line[pts_] :> {colors[[e++]], Line[pts]}]



that is great but not the desired order of colors. I need the inner contours to be the same color

Thanks for the detailed answer. But if I have many plots then I need to fix the color manually for each one, right? would it be possible some how to be automated?
